# JPA Query with input date range

Tags: spring-data-jpa

i have a query where in i am passing date range inputs

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT ord.purchaseOrderNumber,ord.salesOrderNumber,ord.quoteNumber"
            + " FROM Order ord WHERE ord.purchaseOrderNumber :poNumber and ord.receiveDate between to_date(:dateFrom,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date(:dateTo,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

so i am passing valid number to the :poNumber and passing null values to the date placeholders and the query is not returning any values where it should return 1 row based on the :poNumber , so how do i handle this NULL input values to the dates

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need the OR operator between the ord.purchaseOrderNumber and ord.receiveDate

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT ord.purchaseOrderNumber,ord.salesOrderNumber,ord.quoteNumber"

                + " FROM Order ord WHERE ord.purchaseOrderNumber :poNumber OR (ord.receiveDate between to_date(:dateFrom,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date(:dateTo,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

Comment: do you have null values for dateFrom in you DB? if not consider using [CriteriaAPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html), so that you can exclude date comparison for null values of it

Comment: we will not have any null values but this is a search functionality, by the way i am using spring-data jpa in any case how do we fix above without going to CriteriaAPI

Comment: Use Criteria API, And you can add a custom behavior to your spring-data repository as shown here  [Adding custom behavior to single repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)